# Tokenize and stopword don't work in Tweets DB using RapidMiner

Tags: twitter, tokenize, stop-words, rapidminer, text-classification

I would like tokenize and apply stop word filter on Twitter comments contained in a database, but Process Document does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

My goal is to apply these filters but keep the comments in rows instead of a single word vector.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<process version="5.3.015">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="read_database" compatibility="5.3.015" expanded="true" height="60" name="Server Connection (2)" width="90" x="45" y="30">
        <parameter key="connection" value="sqlserver2014"/>
        <parameter key="query" value="select top 60 tweetid,content from [Tweets General]"/>
        <enumeration key="parameters"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:data_to_documents" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Data to Documents" width="90" x="246" y="30">
        <parameter key="select_attributes_and_weights" value="true"/>
        <list key="specify_weights"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="text:process_documents" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="94" name="Process Documents" width="90" x="447" y="30">
        <process expanded="true">
          <operator activated="true" class="text:tokenize" compatibility="5.3.002" expanded="true" height="60" name="Tokenize (3)" width="90" x="246" y="75"/>
          <connect from_port="document" to_op="Tokenize (3)" to_port="document"/>
          <connect from_op="Tokenize (3)" from_port="document" to_port="document 1"/>
          <portSpacing port="source_document" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 1" spacing="0"/>
          <portSpacing port="sink_document 2" spacing="0"/>
        </process>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Server Connection (2)" from_port="output" to_op="Data to Documents" to_port="example set"/>
      <connect from_op="Data to Documents" from_port="documents" to_op="Process Documents" to_port="documents 1"/>
      <connect from_op="Process Documents" from_port="example set" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert any attributes of type nominal to be of type text before the `Data to Documents` operator. The operator `Nominal to Text` will do this. You also need to set the option `select attributes and weights` to false in `Data to Documents` because I think the setting you have will deselect everything.